# Graph Anomalies Stacked Area Chart ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked area chart of negative and positive values showing the composition of the long and short weights of sectors in a portfolio. These values can vary between negative and positive, so ideally I would like something like:

[image]

However, the same sector can have a positive weight at one date and negative weight at another. Unfortunately, ggplot2 tries to connect these values, so if for example a sector is positive on one day, then negative for a time period, and then positive again, gglpot2 will draw a connecting line between the two positive values. This looks like:

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of these connecting lines? Here is sample of my data and code.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

sectorMelt <- melt(exampleData, id = 'date')
longSector <- sectorMelt[which(sectorMelt$value > 0),]
shortSector <- sectorMelt[which(sectorMelt$value < 0),]

ggplot() +
    geom_area(data = longSector, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), stat = 'identity') +
    geom_area(data = shortSector, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), stat = 'identity')

< dput(exampleData)
structure(list(date = structure(c(13880, 13881, 13882, 13885, 
13886, 13887, 13888, 13889, 13892, 13893, 13894, 13895, 13896, 
13900, 13901, 13902, 13903, 13906, 13907, 13908, 13909, 13910, 
13913, 13914, 13915, 13916, 13917, 13920, 13921, 13922, 13923, 
13924, 13928, 13929, 13930, 13931, 13934, 13935, 13936, 13937, 
13938, 13941, 13942, 13943, 13944, 13945, 13948, 13949, 13950, 
13951, 13952, 13955, 13956, 13957, 13958, 13962, 13963, 13964, 
13965, 13966, 13969, 13970, 13971, 13972, 13973, 13976, 13977, 
13978, 13979, 13980, 13983, 13984, 13985, 13986, 13987, 13990, 
13991, 13992, 13993, 13994, 13997, 13998, 13999, 14000, 14001, 
14004, 14005, 14006, 14007, 14008, 14011, 14012, 14013, 14014, 
14015, 14018, 14019, 14020, 14021, 14022, 14026, 14027, 14028, 
14029, 14032, 14033, 14034, 14035, 14036, 14039, 14040, 14041, 
14042, 14043, 14046, 14047, 14048, 14049, 14050, 14053, 14054, 
14055, 14056, 14057, 14060), class = "Date"), V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.004016064, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.004016064, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Basic.Materials = c(0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 
0.016064256, 0.016129032, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0.011870058, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0, 0, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, -0.008032128, 
-0.016064256, -0.024096384, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, 
-0.016064256, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.032, -0.032, -0.024096384, -0.024, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, 
-0.024096384, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.02008032, 
-0.028112448, -0.024096384, -0.028112448, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.024096384, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.056224896, -0.04016064, 
-0.024096384, -0.024096384, 0, -0.008032128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008032128, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Communications = c(-0.056224896, 
-0.048192768, -0.056224896, -0.056224896, -0.052419354, -0.064257024, 
-0.056224896, -0.056224896, -0.06472665, -0.064257024, -0.056224896, 
-0.056224896, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.036144576, -0.04016064, 
-0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, 
-0.008032128, -0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 
0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.016064256, 
0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.008, 0.024, 
0.024096384, 0.024, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0.016064256, 0.008032128, 0, 0.016064256, 0.008032128, 0, 0, 
0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.016064256, 0.008032128, 
0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.016064256, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 
0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.024096384, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 
0.008032128, 0, 0, 0.004016064, 0.016064256, 0, 0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, -0.036144576, -0.032128512, -0.016064256, -0.024096384, 
-0.032128512, -0.048192768, -0.032, -0.048, -0.048, -0.048, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.044176704, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.024096384, 
-0.02008032, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.02008032, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, -0.028112448, -0.028112448, 
-0.032128512), Consumer..Cyclical = c(-0.008032128, -0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, -0.008032128, 0, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.016064256, 
0.02359437, 0.024096384, 0.012048192, 0.02008032, 0.008032128, 
0, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.012048192, 0, 0.004016064, 
0.004016064, -0.004016064, -0.008032128, -0.004016064, 0.004016064, 
0.004016064, -0.004016064, -0.004016064, -0.012048192, -0.012048192, 
-0.02008032, -0.004016064, 0.004016064, 0.012048192, 0.012048192, 
0.012048192, 0, -0.004016064, -0.004016064, -0.004016064, 0.012048192, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.008032128, 0.012, 0.024096384, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.02008032, 0.028112448, 0.02008032, 0.012048192, 0.02008032, 
0.012048192, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 0.04016064, 0.048192768, 
0.048192768, 0.052208832, 0.056224896, 0.06024096, 0.044176704, 
0.052208832, 0.052208832, 0.052208832, 0.068273088, 0.068273088, 
0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.076305216, 0.076305216, 0.068273088, 
0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.06024096, 0.044176704, 0.044176704, 
0.044176704, 0.032128512, 0.04016064, 0.032128512, 0.04016064, 
0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.032128512, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032, 0.032, 0.016, 0.016, 0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, 0, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, 
-0.024096384, -0.016064256, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.032128512, -0.036144576, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, 
-0.04016064, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, 
-0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384
), Consumer..Non.cyclical = c(-0.06024096, -0.064257024, -0.064257024, 
-0.06024096, -0.096774192, -0.076305216, -0.092369472, -0.1004016, 
-0.077195886, -0.112449792, -0.108433728, -0.116465856, -0.108433728, 
-0.1004016, -0.076305216, -0.06024096, -0.06024096, -0.06024096, 
-0.056224896, -0.044176704, -0.052208832, -0.028112448, -0.036144576, 
-0.076305216, -0.076305216, -0.068273088, -0.06024096, -0.052208832, 
-0.072289152, -0.06024096, -0.064257024, -0.076305216, -0.076305216, 
-0.072289152, -0.064257024, -0.052208832, -0.06024096, -0.072289152, 
-0.068273088, -0.068273088, -0.068, -0.06, -0.084337344, -0.076, 
-0.068273088, -0.076305216, -0.068273088, -0.06024096, -0.068273088, 
-0.06024096, -0.06024096, -0.06024096, -0.052208832, -0.06024096, 
-0.072289152, -0.072289152, -0.072289152, -0.072289152, -0.08032128, 
-0.084337344, -0.084337344, -0.068273088, -0.068273088, -0.068273088, 
-0.068273088, -0.076305216, -0.068273088, -0.076305216, -0.068273088, 
-0.068273088, -0.068273088, -0.084337344, -0.076305216, -0.076305216, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.036144576, -0.048192768, -0.052208832, -0.048192768, 
-0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.028112448, -0.044176704, -0.048192768, 
-0.056, -0.056, -0.04, -0.048, -0.036144576, -0.024096384, -0.028112448, 
-0.028112448, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.044176704, 
-0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.044176704, 
-0.052208832, -0.052208832, -0.052208832, -0.052208832, -0.048192768, 
-0.056224896, -0.056224896, -0.044176704, -0.04016064, -0.024096384, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.044176704, 
-0.048192768, -0.056224896, -0.056224896, -0.048192768), Diversified = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004, 
0.004, 0.004016064, 0.004, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.004, -0.004, -0.004, -0.004, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Energy = c(0, 0, -0.008032128, 
-0.008032128, 0, -0.008032128, 0.004016064, -0.008032128, -0.00833981400000001, 
0, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 
0.024096384, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 
0.044176704, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.044176704, 0.056224896, 
0.052208832, 0.036144576, 0.02008032, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 0.02008032, 
0.032128512, 0.028112448, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 
0.036, 0.028, 0.036144576, 0.028, 0.028112448, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 
0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 
0.036144576, 0.044176704, 0.052208832, 0.044176704, 0.044176704, 
0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 0.044176704, 
0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.02008032, 0.02008032, 0.012048192, 0.012048192, 0.012048192, 
0.012048192, 0.012048192, 0.012048192, 0.012048192, 0.004016064, 
-0.004016064, 0.02008032, 0.012048192, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.044176704, 0.044176704, 0.04016064, 0.044176704, 
0.044176704, 0.044176704, 0.028, 0.044, 0.052, 0.052, 0.052208832, 
0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.02008032, 0.02008032, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 0.044176704, 0.044176704, 
0.044176704, 0.052208832, 0.052208832, 0.036144576, 0.024096384, 
0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 
0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.008032128, 0.02008032, 0.016064256, 
-0.008032128, 0, 0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128
), Financial = c(0.08032128, 0.08032128, 0.08032128, 0.08032128, 
0.08064516, 0.08032128, 0.08032128, 0.068273088, 0.071706168, 
0.08032128, 0.064257024, 0.056224896, 0.04016064, 0.024096384, 
0.008032128, 0, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.056224896, -0.064257024, -0.072289152, -0.056224896, -0.064257024, 
-0.08032128, -0.072289152, -0.064257024, -0.056224896, -0.056224896, 
-0.056224896, -0.056224896, -0.064257024, -0.064257024, -0.056224896, 
-0.052208832, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.04, -0.048, -0.048192768, -0.048, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.036144576, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.064257024, -0.064257024, 
-0.064257024, -0.036144576, -0.044176704, -0.036144576, -0.04016064, 
-0.056224896, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.008032128, 0.024096384, 0.02008032, 0.028112448, 
0.036144576, 0.044176704, 0.036144576, 0.032128512, 0.036144576, 
0.032128512, 0.044176704, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.028112448, 
0.02008032, 0.036144576, 0.036144576, 0.044, 0.044, 0.052, 0.06, 
0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 
0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.064257024, 
0.064257024, 0.064257024, 0.072289152, 0.072289152, 0.072289152, 
0.072289152, 0.072289152, 0.076305216, 0.076305216, 0.076305216, 
0.068273088, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.056224896, 
0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.064257024
), Industrial = c(0.048192768, 0.044176704, 0.052208832, 0.048192768, 
0.06048387, 0.064257024, 0.052208832, 0.068273088, 0.059852304, 
0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.052208832, 0.076305216, 0.076305216, 
0.06024096, 0.068273088, 0.068273088, 0.076305216, 0.076305216, 
0.092369472, 0.08032128, 0.1004016, 0.096385536, 0.088353408, 
0.084337344, 0.092369472, 0.096385536, 0.112449792, 0.108433728, 
0.1004016, 0.108433728, 0.104417664, 0.1004016, 0.1004016, 0.1004016, 
0.088353408, 0.092369472, 0.096385536, 0.084337344, 0.076305216, 
0.084, 0.076, 0.084337344, 0.084, 0.076305216, 0.084337344, 0.084337344, 
0.088353408, 0.092369472, 0.092369472, 0.1004016, 0.084337344, 
0.084337344, 0.076305216, 0.088353408, 0.084337344, 0.068273088, 
0.06024096, 0.068273088, 0.06024096, 0.068273088, 0.06024096, 
0.052208832, 0.044176704, 0.052208832, 0.052208832, 0.06024096, 
0.06024096, 0.06024096, 0.052208832, 0.052208832, 0.06024096, 
0.044176704, 0.028112448, 0.02008032, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.02008032, 0.012048192, -0.004016064, -0.012048192, 
-0.004016064, -0.004016064, -0.016064256, -0.02008032, -0.028112448, 
-0.028112448, -0.02008032, -0.012, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02008032, 
0, -0.012048192, 0.012048192, 0.024096384, 0.04016064, 0.032128512, 
0.028112448, 0.02008032, 0.024096384, 0.02008032, 0.02008032, 
0.024096384, 0.028112448, 0.04016064, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 
0.04016064, 0.044176704, 0.028112448, 0.024096384, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.028112448, 0.024096384, 0.032128512, 0.024096384, 
0.04016064, 0.028112448, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 0.048192768
), Technology = c(-0.068273088, -0.068273088, -0.06024096, -0.052208832, 
-0.048387096, -0.06024096, -0.052208832, -0.044176704, -0.056759298, 
-0.036144576, -0.036144576, -0.036144576, -0.048192768, -0.036144576, 
-0.02008032, -0.048192768, -0.036144576, -0.036144576, -0.028112448, 
-0.024096384, 0.012048192, -0.012048192, 0.004016064, 0.012048192, 
0.012048192, 0.024096384, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.032128512, 0.036144576, 0.044176704, 0.06024096, 0.052208832, 
0.036144576, 0.044176704, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 0.056224896, 
0.056224896, 0.044, 0.036, 0.048192768, 0.044, 0.044176704, 0.024096384, 
0.016064256, 0.028112448, 0.016064256, 0.016064256, 0.024096384, 
0.02008032, 0.032128512, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 0.028112448, 
0.028112448, 0.02008032, 0.036144576, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 
0.04016064, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 
0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 
0.032128512, 0.016064256, 0.008032128, 0, 0, -0.008032128, -0.032128512, 
-0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.016064256, -0.008032128, 
-0.016064256, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, -0.016064256, -0.02008032, 
-0.024, -0.016, -0.032, -0.032, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.048192768, 
-0.056224896, -0.048192768, -0.044176704, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, 
-0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384, -0.024096384), Utilities = c(0.048192768, 
0.048192768, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04032258, 0.04016064, 
0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.0399987, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 0.04016064, 
0.04016064, 0.044176704, 0.04016064, 0.048192768, 0.048192768, 
0.04016064, 0.024096384, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 0.008032128, 
0, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.008032128, -0.016064256, -0.024096384, 
-0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.044176704, 
-0.04016064, -0.032128512, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.056, -0.048, -0.048192768, -0.048, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.04016064, 
-0.04016064, -0.04016064, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, -0.048192768, 
-0.048192768, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, -0.032128512, -0.024096384, 
-0.024096384, -0.024096384, 0, 0.008032128, 0.024096384, 0.024, 
0.024, 0.024, 0.024, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 
0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 0.024096384, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.024096384, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.032128512, 
0.032128512, 0.032128512, 0.024096384), NA. = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("date", 
"V1", "Basic.Materials", "Communications", "Consumer..Cyclical", 
"Consumer..Non.cyclical", "Diversified", "Energy", "Financial", 
"Industrial", "Technology", "Utilities", "NA."), row.names = 755:879, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating the long and short graphs separately and then setting all the negative values to 0 in the long data set and vice versa in the short data set. So, I just modified the code with this.

```
sectorMelt <- melt(exampleData, id = 'date')
longSector <- sectorMelt
shortSector <- sectorMelt

longSector$value[which(longSector$value < 0)] <- rep(0, length(which(longSector$value < 0)))
shortSector$value[which(shortSector$value > 0)] <- rep(0, length(which(shortSector$value > 0)))

ggplot() +
    geom_area(data = longSector, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), stat = 'identity') +
    geom_area(data = shortSector, aes(x = date, y = value, fill = variable), stat = 'identity')
```

So now it looks like this:[image]